# Was the disparity in Wolverine's height an issue?

Tags: marvel, x-men

According to Marvel comics, Wolverine is only 5'3 in height [Wolverine | Character](http://marvel.com/characters/66/wolverine).

But Hugh Jackman is 6'3 in height. Is this a misrepresentation of the Wolverine character in the movies?

[image]

Comment: Comics ≠ movies, not by a long shot…

Comment: I think if you cut out the last line, and changed it something like "Has anyone associated with the films commented on this?" it would not be opinion-based.

Comment: Speaking personally, it completely ruined the movies for me. Every time he walked through a doorway, I was thinking “*Damnit*, there should be more space between the top of his head and the upper frame of the door! Why are these Hollywood cowboys so damned *sloppy*?!?!?”

Comment: Can't believe it, Wolverine is taller than Cyclops in the movies

Comment: If Tom Cruise can play Jack Reacher, physical stature is no limitation to movie adaptations.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes and no.

In the earlier films, Jackman's height wasn't a big issue. There was evidently a conscious decision **to cast him *against* character**

> *During the interview, X-Men producer Lauren Shuler Donner recalled why
>   Singer decided Jackman was the man to play Logan in 2000’s X-Men.
>   **“Hugh was a lot taller than the character, and Bryan wasn’t sure if he
>   was the right guy,”** she said. “So I said, ‘Let me send him up to you
>   in Toronto,’ and Hugh went up, and Anna Paquin was there already, and
>   they did a scene together, and after Bryan yelled ‘Cut!’ one of the
>   crewmembers said, ‘Wow! That’s Wolverine.’ ”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Hugh Jackman Couldn’t Turn Down X-Men: Days of Future Past](http://spinoff.comicbookresources.com/2013/02/14/hugh-jackman-couldnt-turn-down-x-men-days-of-future-past/)</sup></sub>

When it came to the stand-alone [The Wolverine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolverine_(film)), the director who was initially slated to direct the film (Darren Aronofsky, a noted comic-book fan) apparently asked Jackman to bulk up slightly, **making him look more like the original comic character.**

> **GB:** *Are you going to have to go back to that intense diet, eating whole chickens so you can get that muscle mass back up?*
>
> **HJ:** *I’m on it right now, mate, already doing it. It’s 6,000 calories a  day, it’s rough.*
>
> **GB:** *How much you weighing?*
>
> **HJ:** *Right now, I’m at 210.*
>
> **GB:** *Wow, so you’re going to be bigger this time? Last time, you looked about, what, 190?*
>
> **HJ:** ***Yeah, right, I was 190, something like that. I don’t know how much I want to give away about it, but Darren said with the last one,
>   ‘Hey you looked great, but you’re so tall that in those long shots you
>   looked kind of like Clint Eastwood, and that’s not Wolverine.” He said
>   that Wolverine, in the comics, is powerful, stocky, you know, he’s
>   short and thick. So he said, ‘I want you to go there, get bigger.’***
>   He’s going to come down after he gets done with all the black-tie
>   events over and done with.
>
> <sup><sub>http://herocomplex.latimes.com/movies/hugh-jackman-to-wolverine-fans-the-planets-are-finally-aligned-to-make-a-great-movie/</sub></sup>